# Clone a github app to heroku

Tags: heroku, github, push, git-clone

I'm a newbie and i want to clone an app from github to heroku. I tried this command

```
heroku git:clone git@github.com:[Creator]/[APPname].git [HerokuappDirectory]
```

But i get  `Resource Not Found`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clone the repo like normal with `git clone git@github...`  . Then cd into the directory and run `heroku create [an optional app name]` . Then you'll have two Git remotes setup, on for the repo (origin), one for the heroku app(heroku). Then 'git push heroku master' will deploy to heroku.